# Atlassian Stash vs Git Client

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

We are planning to use Stash. To my knowledge we already have a Git installation and need to configure Stash to use it. My understanding is that Stash can help configure branches, merges, and other stuff.

So do my development teams need to use Stash to check in code or should they use another Git client?  Is Stash used only by the admin to configure the repositories?

Answer (score 4):

What Atlassian's Stash brings to the party is a really easy way to administer git behind the firewall (or at least self hosted)  - to create repositories, assign user permissions to said repositories and also a really slick user interface to see whats going on.

Can you manage without it? Sure, but it's sometimes so much nicer to just use a nice UI rather than remember the commands.

Git clients (such as [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)) give you a client-side UI to connect to the repository and perform the various commands.

There is also the ability to browse projects and repositories in Stash (discovery!) - something that's only present in git clients if you've already added all the repo URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Stash has many features one among them is Pull request. This option provides capability of reviewing the code. You can write your own plugins with the Java api provided by Stash. 
Branching Strategies are simple to maintain in Stash.
with these Stash is easy to maintain :).
Git client 1.8 and above should be used if you are using Stash.

Is there any other tool like stash? yes gitolite is the tool which does the same task. Gitolite is opensource.